# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

Tags: запятая

Я вижу(,) покрашенный в зеленый цвет(,) потолок.

Answer (score 1):

Нет,запятые не нужны, потому что причастный оборот стоит перед определяемым словом.Я вижу покрашенный в зеленый цвет потолок.